# Write a form in VB.NET that will be the same state when you return to it

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to make a form that when it is return to, it will have the same state for the controls

I have 3 .net pages, testa,testb,testc

testa, sets up the session and has a button to go to testb.  testb has a check box and a button to go to testc.  testc has a button to return to page testb.

I want it so when we leave testc, and then come back the check mark will be in the same state, but it is not. it stays as uncheck when I go from page testc back to page testb

This is what i did,
On the page load event, I set the check box equal to the "button" Session variable.  On the button event I save the button checked state in the Session variable and call page testc

**Code**

*Page A*

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Server.Transfer("testb.aspx")
End Sub
```

*Page b*

```
Partial Class testb
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim t As Boolean
        t = Session.Item("button")
        CheckBox1.Checked = t
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim t As Boolean

        t = CheckBox1.Checked
        Session.Item("button") = t

        Server.Transfer("testc.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

*Page c*

```
Partial Class testc
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Server.Transfer("testb.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Maybe what you're trying to achieve is easier done using the [Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

Data in the Session is stored as an `Object`.  What you'll need to do is get the value from the Session and then convert it to a `Boolean` if it's not `null` (`Nothing` in VB).  We've used this technique before:

```
Dim rawValue As Object = Session.Item("button")
Dim realValue as Boolean

If rawValue IsNot Nothing Then
    realValue = Boolean.Parse(rawValue.ToString())
End If
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answering my quastion, I was able to solve the problem, issue was that the pageload event would get called before the button event, thus the old values would get loaded in, before they where saved.  I use the prerender event instad of onload, worcks fine!

Comment: @Ted - good to hear. You should consider posting your own answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to check the `IsPostBack` property in the `Page_Load` method to decide if the values should be loaded or not.  When it's a postback, don't load from the Session.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim t As Boolean = Session.Item("button")
        CheckBox1.Checked = t
    End If
End Sub
```